# when use systemd start ntpd mount namespace is different from pid 1

Tags: systemd, ntpd, namespace

### when use systemd to start ntpd, why ntpd pid's mount namespace is different from pid 1?

#### when use systemd start ntpd

only mount namespace is different from pid 1;

you see ntpd mnt:[4026532696] , but , pid 1 is mnt:[4026531840]

```
#ll /proc/`pidof ntpd`/ns
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  7 17:58 ipc -> ipc:[4026531839]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  7 17:58 mnt -> mnt:[4026532696]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  7 17:58 net -> net:[4026531968]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  7 17:58 pid -> pid:[4026531836]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  7 17:58 user -> user:[4026531837]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  7 17:58 uts -> uts:[4026531838]

#ll /proc/1/ns
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  7 17:58 ipc -> ipc:[4026531839]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  7 17:58 mnt -> mnt:[4026531840]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  7 17:58 net -> net:[4026531968]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  7 17:58 pid -> pid:[4026531836]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  7 17:58 user -> user:[4026531837]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  7 17:58 uts -> uts:[4026531838]
```

#### when not use systemd to start ntpd

if not use systemd to start ntpd , ntpd pid's mount namespace is same with pid 1 's mount namespace

```
#systemctl stop ntpd

#/usr/sbin/ntpd -u ntp:ntp -g

#ll /proc/`pidof ntpd`/ns
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 20 19:46 ipc -> ipc:[4026531839]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 20 19:46 mnt -> mnt:[4026531840]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 20 19:46 net -> net:[4026531968]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 20 19:46 pid -> pid:[4026531836]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 20 19:46 user -> user:[4026531837]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 20 19:46 uts -> uts:[4026531838]

#ll /proc/1/ns
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  7 17:58 ipc -> ipc:[4026531839]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  7 17:58 mnt -> mnt:[4026531840]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  7 17:58 net -> net:[4026531968]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  7 17:58 pid -> pid:[4026531836]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  7 17:58 user -> user:[4026531837]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  7 17:58 uts -> uts:[4026531838]
```

#### other daemon started by systemd looks good

sshd pid is 1252

```
#ll /proc/1252/ns/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 20 19:52 ipc -> ipc:[4026531839]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 20 19:52 mnt -> mnt:[4026531840]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 20 19:52 net -> net:[4026531968]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 20 19:52 pid -> pid:[4026531836]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 20 19:52 user -> user:[4026531837]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 20 19:52 uts -> uts:[4026531838]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will vary from one distro to the next, but I think that this is a result of the use of the `PrivateTmp: true` feature of systemd.

As described in the **Service-Private /tmp** section of [this](http://0pointer.net/blog/projects/security.html) blog post from Lennart Poettering:

> Internally, this feature makes use of file system namespaces of the kernel. If enabled a new file system namespace is opened inheritng most of the host hierarchy with the exception of /tmp

See, for example, [this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=782520) requesting that this option be added to Fedora.